# Javamail, Weblogic, IMAP, SSL and Exchange 2010

Tags: ssl, weblogic, imap, jakarta-mail, exchange-server-2010

first of all, sorry for my english (I'm from Spain)

I'm trying to connect to an Exchange 2010 mail server with IMAP and SSL from Javamail inside a Weblogic 8.1 server.

This is my code

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

// IMAP
// Disable TLS
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "false");

// Use SSL
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

// Use port 993
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
prop.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");

prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.class", "com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host, user, password);
```

At this point, I get  **javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Command received in Invalid state**.
The user parameter is a combination of "domain\user-login\mail-box-alias". I use this because I saw it in this way in a how-to guide.
I already installed a valid SSL certificade in my Weblogic Server.

I don't know where the error is.

With debug I get this:

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.

A0 CAPABILITY

CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+

A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.

A1 LOGIN "domain\user\mailbox-alias" password

A1 BAD Command received in Invalid state.

ERROR 2: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Command received in Invalid state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue. It was a problem of javamail version, it was too old for Exchange 2010. I upgrated to 1.4 version and worked. Until now I was using Javamail 1.1.3.

Comment: hey, solved the problem? Can you help me here(stackoverflow.com/q/36483341/3703397)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using port 993, you want `imaps` instead of `imap` as your protocol:

```
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
```

On port 143, the connection is plaintext.  You can then optionally start a TLS encryption layer by issuing the `STARTTLS` IMAP command.  (That's what's controlled by the `mail.imap.starttls.enable` property.)

On port 993, the initial connection *must* be an encrypted SSL connection.  This SSL handshake has to be done before any text is sent or received from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what does it means. Must I encrypt user and password somehow? Is there any example code? I don't find anything.

Comment: No. All you need to do is change "imap" to "imaps" just like in that sample line of code I included. The rest of the explanation is for anyone who cares about the details of why, but you don't need to understand it to get things working.

Comment: I did it and now I get this exception "javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for imaps"

Comment: Set the property `mail.debug` to `true` and see what's printed to stdout.  You should see a line saying `DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers` followed by a bunch of entries, one of which should be for `imaps`.  If all else fails, you can try to set the property `mail.imaps.class` to `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore`.

Comment: After setting mail.debug to true I got this: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc] Does this mean my Java installation doesn't support imaps? Setting mail.imaps.class to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore didn't help.

Comment: I think it might help if you posted your current code and the entire JavaMail `DEBUG` dump from when you run it...

Comment: OK.  Try removing the line that says `prop.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "false");` -- since you're not actually using `imaps`, you're going to need to enable `STARTTLS`.

Comment: It didn't work either. I get "A1 BAD Command received in Invalid state." even if I use an empty Properties.

Comment: Hey guys, hey, solved the problem? Can you help me here(stackoverflow.com/q/36483341/3703397)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Exchange 2010 is set up to allow user/pwd based logins.